# Using JQuery Show/Hide to hide/show a div, but clicking on button doesn't have an effect

Tags: jquery, html, css, hide, show

I'm having trouble in having my link (represented by an image, and off to the left side of the page) be actually effective in causing a div (which contains a sentence, and in the center) to show up/hide when the link is clicked on.

Here's my code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html lang="ja">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta name="description" content="practice">
<meta name="keywords" content="practice">
<title>Practice</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Script-Type" content="text/javascript">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery_regular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.backstretch.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/top_javascript.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery_rollover.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery_slideout.js"></script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet/top_style.css" type="text/css" media="all">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />
</head>
<body onLoad="fontSizeChg(0);">
    <div id="top_wrapper">

        <div id="top_main_box">
        <div id="slide">
            <div id="top_main_l_box">

                <div id="top_main_logo"><img src="image/title.png" alt=""></div>

                <ul id="top_main_navi_1">
                    <li id="about"><a><img src="image/about.png" alt="" class="rollover"></a></li>
                    <li><a><img src="image/member.png" alt="" class="rollover"></a></li>
                    <li><a><img src="image/photo.png" alt="" class="rollover"></a></li>
                    <li><a><img src="image/links.png" alt="" class="rollover"></a></li>
                    <li><a><img src="image/contact.png" alt="" class="rollover"></a></li>
                </ul>



            </div>
            <div id="about_this">
                    This is all the things about our page
            </div>

            <div id="top_main_r_box">

                <div id="top_main_catch"><img src="image/catch.png" alt=""></div>

            </div>
                <div id="slideout" class="showbg"><img src="image/slideout.png"></div>
                <div id="slidein" class="showcont"><img src="image/slidein.png"></div>

            <br class="c_clear">
        </div>
        </div>
```

Here's my CSS:

```
#about{
}

#about_this{
    position: fixed;
    top: 200px;
    left: 500px;
}
```

Here's my JQuery:

```
$('#about').toggle(function () {
    $('#about_this').hide();
}, function () {
    $('#about_this').show();
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What version of jQuery? The `toggle()` method now only shows/hides an element, it no longer offers a '[function-toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/)' (whereas before it would look at the arguments and either show/hide or toggle between a series of function calls). Removedin jQuery 1.9.

Comment: toggle is not an event

Comment: Hi, I apologize but I actually don't really know what version I'm using as I really am just a beginner at this. If toggle is unavailable as an option for me, what would be the best thing to do in causing the div to appear and disappear when the "link" is clicked on?

Comment: `$('#about').on('click', function(){ $('#about_this').toggle(); });`

Comment: Thank you all so much for the responses, but I still am not able to cause the div to disappear or reappear. 

Is there something else wrong with the rest of my code in my html?

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#about").click(function(){
        $("#about_this").toggle();
   });
 });
 </script>
```

also use the latest version of jQuery

Answer (score 1):

you have to add an action listner first

```
$("#about_this").click(function(){
    $("#about_this").toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Toggle is not an event, but it is a method : http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

just change your JQuery code to this :

```
$('#about').click(function () {
    $('#about_this').toggle();
});
```

if you are using a JQuery version Post 1.7 you should use the click event like so :

```
$('#about').on("click", function () {
    $('#about_this').toggle();
});
```

### Checking your version of JQuery :

```
if (typeof jQuery != 'undefined') {  
    // jQuery is loaded => print the version
    alert(jQuery.fn.jquery);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding this correctly, you will want to initially hide #about_this, so set its to display none in the CSS, then make it visible when clicked, and invisible when clicked again. In addition to on click you can use hover also.

```
 #about_this{
    position: fixed;
    top: 200px;
    left: 500px;
    display:none;
  }


$('#about').on('click', function(){
   $('#about_this').toggle();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to run `.hide()` and `.show()` when using `.toggle()`

Here's an example with options

`$("#about").click(function() {
    $("#about_this").toggle("slow",function(){
        //Animation complete.
    });
});`